# How can I assign KEYS to a value in client.keys() function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

I am in trouble, I wanted to assign KEYS which are defined in REDIS to a value in redisClient.keys function but I could not do that, I tried to console log it and I got a result which is correct however it cannot be read from outside of that keys function. If you help me, I will be appreciated.

```js
const redis = require('redis');
const redisClient = redis.createClient();
var values ;

redisClient.flushall();

redisClient.hmset('Angelica', { "Blues Traveler": 3.5, "Broken Bells": 2.0, "Norah Jones": 4.5, "Phoenix": 5.0, "Slightly Stoopid": 1.5, "The Strokes": 2.5, "Vampire Weekend": 2.0 });
redisClient.hmset('Bill', { "Blues Traveler": 2.0, "Broken Bells": 3.5, "Deadmau5": 4.0, "Phoenix": 2.0, "Slightly Stoopid": 3.5, "Vampire Weekend": 3.0 });
redisClient.hmset('Dan', { "Blues Traveler": 3.0, "Broken Bells": 4.0, "Deadmau5": 4.5, "Phoenix": 3.0, "Slightly Stoopid": 4.5, "The Strokes": 4.0, "Vampire Weekend": 2.0 });
redisClient.hmset('Hailey', { "Broken Bells": 4.0, "Deadmau5": 1.0, "Norah Jones": 4.0, "The Strokes": 4.0, "Vampire Weekend": 1.0 });
redisClient.hmset('Jordyn', { "Broken Bells": 4.5, "Deadmau5": 4.0, "Norah Jones": 5.0, "Phoenix": 5.0, "Slightly Stoopid": 4.5, "The Strokes": 4.0, "Vampire Weekend": 4.0 });
redisClient.hmset('Sam', { "Blues Traveler": 5.0, "Broken Bells": 2.0, "Norah Jones": 3.0, "Phoenix": 5.0, "Slightly Stoopid": 4.0, "The Strokes": 5.0 });
redisClient.hmset('Veronica', { "Blues Traveler": 3.0, "Norah Jones": 5.0, "Phoenix": 4.0, "Slightly Stoopid": 2.5, "The Strokes": 3.0 });
redisClient.hmset('Chan', { "Blues Traveler": 5.0, "Broken Bells": 1.0, "Deadmau5": 1.0, "Norah Jones": 3.0, "Phoenix": 5, "Slightly Stoopid": 1.0 });

    redisClient.keys('*', (err, responde) => {
        redisClient.hmget(responde);
        values=responde.toLocaleString()
        console.log(responde.toLocaleString())
    })

console.log( values)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may find the `console.log( values)` is actually executed before the callback in the `redisClient.keys()` method.

Comment: Yeah. I noticed that, Thank You Buddy.